How to store hashmap objects inside Map<String,Object> upto 3 level and output should be value from 3rd level
PFB the code for question:
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,Object> map1 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        Map<String,Object> map3 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        
        map1.put("A", "a");
        map1.put("B", map2);
        map1.put("C", 1);
        
        map2.put("A", "a");
        map2.put("B", map3);
        map2.put("C", 1);
        
        map3.put("A", "a");
        map3.put("B", "b");
        map3.put("C", 1);
        
        getValue("B",map1);
    }

    public static Object getValue(String s, Map<String,Object> map) {
    
    }
}

This was asked in an interview, and I am clueless. The interviewer wanted the getValue method to return only "b" whereas it's returning the complete map3 object value.
Can someone pls help

Why then did you not do getValue("B",map3);?

@g00se : because it was condition given by him to pass map1 object in getvalue method

Recursive solution for getValue():

Get a value from map which is associated with the key s.
If type of this value is Map:


Return getValue() with arguments s and value.
Otherwise - return the value.

public static Object getValue(String s, Map<String, Object> map) {
    Object value = map.get(s);
    if (value instanceof Map) {
        return getValue(s, (Map<String, Object>) value);
    }
    return value;
}

To avoid recursion and type safety warning it can be converted to a loop:
public static Object getValue(String s, Map<String, Object> map) {
    Object value = map;
    while (value instanceof Map) {
        value = ((Map<?, ?>) value).get(s);
    }
    return value;
}


I'm offering two solutions to this problem:
The first one is a more generic approach that keeps descending until it reaches the most nested Map. At that point, the method returns the value corresponded to the given key.
public static Object getValue1(String s, Map<String, Object> map) {
    //Terminal case which checks whether there is any value corresponded to the key
    if (map.get(s) == null) {
        return null;
    }

    //Recursive call if the value corresponded to the key is an instance of Map
    if (map.get(s) instanceof Map) {
        return getValue1(s, (Map<String, Object>) map.get(s));
    }

    //Final step where we've reached the most nested Map and we're returning the key's value
    return map.get(s);
}

The second one returns a value from a specific level, which could also be a Map.
I'm also providing this solution, since in your question the interviewer asked for a very specific level to be returned, which of course corresponds to the final one that doesn't contain any Maps. I just thought that this could be another possible variation to attach.
public static Object getValue2(String s, Map<String, Object> map, int levelDepth) {
    return getValue2Helper(s, map, levelDepth, 0);
}

private static Object getValue2Helper(String s, Map<String, Object> map, int levelDepth, int levelCounter) {
    //Terminal case where we've reached the level before the desired one and return the corresponding value
    if (levelCounter + 1 == levelDepth) {
        return map.get(s);
    }

    //Terminal case where the level requested goes beyond the levels available
    if (!(map.get(s) instanceof Map)){
        return map.get(s);
    }

    //Recursive call to the next level
    return getValue2Helper(s, (Map<String, Object>) map.get(s), levelDepth, levelCounter + 1);
}

You can also test both solutions at oneCompiler
